# "-u {vimrc}" not working as expected

Tags: vimrc, command-line, options

I am trying to set up vim so I can get different functions in with different files (i.e. x.lisp and x.scm) and in the manual it says starting with the option "-u ufile"  uses "ufile" as the vimrc

My problem is that the "-u ufile" option does not work as expected. The shortcut for `<C-X><C-O>` , instead of executing the commands it literally prints out `<C-X><C-O>`

here is the exact code

```
 :inoremap <C-h> <C-X><C-O>
```

"this works in the .vimrc file but does nothing on the -u ufile.

```
 :inoremap ^^ <C-X><C-O>
```

"this works in the .vimrc file but literally prints out `<C-X><C-O>` on the -u ufile.

Is there something wrong with the -u option or am I not understanding the manual correctly?

Note:
I have managed to do what I want using the  "-s sfile" option, (even though it messes up my history somewhat) but to comment i need to use '| # "comment ' otherwise it is read as well for some reason. I am still curious as to why the -u option does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you start vim with -u {vimrc} then vim will not automatically switch off compatibility mode.

You need to have `set nocp` in your ufile (best as the first line)

Comment: or use `-N` argument